# exponential probability

Tags: probability

A clerk in the claims department of an insurance company is waiting for his next
customer to call. He knows that the waiting time for the next man to call is statistically
different form the waiting time for the next woman to call: the first time is exponential
with mean λ1, and the second time is exponential with mean λ2. Based on this, what
is the probability that the next person who calls will be a man instead of a woman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t_1$ denote the first time a man calls, and let $t_2$ denote the first time a woman calls. These are exponential random variables with means $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. We are looking for the probability $\mathbb P(t_1<t_2)$. To find this probability, we integrate over all pairs of times $(t_1,t_2)$ for which $t_1<t_2$. In other words, $t_1$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$, then $t_2$ ranges from $t_1$ to $\infty$.
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(t_1<t_2)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1 t_1}\int_{t_1}^{\infty}\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2 t_2}\ dt_2\ dt_1\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1 t_1}\left[-e^{-\lambda_2 t_2}\right]_{t_1}^{\infty}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1 t_1}e^{-\lambda_2 t_1}\\
&=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}.\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: thank you! It makes a lot of sense! This is helpful!